# How to Close a CVS Module

Tags: cvs

I there a way to tell all users not to use a CVS module (i.e. project) anymore?
Something like an "end of production" or "moved to ..." flag?

I mean other than deleting all the files in the module as my co-workers like to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put a cvs lock in the base directory of the module on the cvs server to prevent checkouts. `touch "#cvs.lock"`.

Additionally, a system like [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) could allow developers to browse the contents of the old source code.

Comment: Note that this does not prevent commits by the user who created the lock file

Comment: This only prevents access to the directoy in which the lock file resides, not recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Make all of the files read-only. Or do you want to prevent reads too?

**Edit**: this command will recursively remove write permission from files in a directory tree, on a *nix system, assuming you're in the root of the directory tree you want to change.

```
find . -type f | xargs chmod gou-w
```

(I had previously posted a command in a comment below that was just plain wrong.)

Comment: no, read only would be fine. I there a CVS statement to do that or did you mean via filesystem means?

Comment: How do you mark files read only? If you explicitly change the filesystem permissions this will prevent a read only checkout too because the cvs lock file cannot be written during checkout.

Comment: @leif81 - My comment above was incorrect. (I'll delete the comment and amend my answer. The command in the comment removed *read* permissions, and it also affected directories.) If you leave the  write permissions on the directories, you should still be able to create a lock file, right?